# java: Unknown property return type, using MapStruct

Tags: lombok, mapstruct

I'm using `mapStruct` and `lombok`,
during the property mapping I encountered this error
how can I fix it?

and here is my `pom.xml`

```html
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--For generat Getter and setter and more fonction on class-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<!--For Mappgin POJO TO DTO and vis virsal-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

<!--For mapping auto process generated-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

here is a screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMiCc.png)

Comment: Did you install the Lombok plugin and enable annotation processing?

Comment: there's plenty of info to find on MapStruct and Lombok. Most problems come down to the way Lombok works: it hacks itself into implementation of the compiler rather than using the APT interface (which forbids modifying existing classes). Anyway.. Solutions have been devised in the past. checkout https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1159 for instance. The last answer proposes to update to MapStruct 1.3.1.final and 1.16.14 of Lombok.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1159) issue, please updating to the latest version of Lombok seems to resolve the problem.

Another way would be to use a different maven project for the DTO's, entities the have the Lombok annotations than the dependent maven project using MapStruct.